# Why my tensorboard is showing a discontinued output?

Tags: python-3.x, validation, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am running a neural network with logging of *training accuracy*,*Validation accuracy and validation loss*. here is my code snippet.

```
def show_progress(epoch, feed_dict_train, feed_dict_validate, val_loss):

    acc = session.run(accuracy, feed_dict=feed_dict_train)

    val_acc = session.run(accuracy, feed_dict=feed_dict_validate)

    msg = "Training Epoch {0} --- Training Accuracy: {1:>6.1%}, Validation Accuracy: {2:>6.1%},  Validation Loss: {3:.3f}"

    print(msg.format(epoch + 1, acc, val_acc, val_loss))
    return acc,val_acc



total_iterations = 0

#writer=tf.summary.FileWriter(options.tensorboard,session)

saver = tf.train.Saver()

def train(num_iteration):
    global total_iterations
    writer=tf.summary.FileWriter(options.tensorboard,session.graph)
    #global writer
    for i in range(total_iterations,
                   total_iterations + num_iteration):

        x_batch, y_true_batch, _, cls_batch = data.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        x_valid_batch, y_valid_batch, _, valid_cls_batch = data.valid.next_batch(batch_size)


        feed_dict_tr = {x: x_batch,
                           y_true: y_true_batch}
        feed_dict_val = {x: x_valid_batch,
                              y_true: y_valid_batch}

        session.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict_tr)

        if i % 10 == 0:

            val_loss = session.run(cost, feed_dict=feed_dict_val)
            epoch = int(i /10)    

            accu,valid_accu=show_progress(epoch, feed_dict_tr, feed_dict_val, val_loss)
            #getting values for visualising inside the tensorboard

            tf.summary.scalar("training_accuracy",accu)
            tf.summary.scalar("Validation_accuracy",valid_accu)
            tf.summary.scalar("Validation_loss",val_loss)
            #tf.summary.scalar("epoch",epoch)

            #merging all the values (serializing)

            merged=tf.summary.merge_all()
            summary=session.run(merged)

            #adding them to the events directory 
            writer.add_summary(summary,epoch)
            saver.save(session, options.save)


    total_iterations += num_iteration

train(num_iteration=10)
```

Now I am getting a tensor board output, as for each epoch the accuracy,validation accuracy and validation loss as separate plots with single points.

For each epoch I am getting these three plots again with another point.

I want to get a continuous  points for these three plots so as it forms a line graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your call to `tf.summary.scalar()` will create a node in the computation graph. Specifically, in your code, the calls are inside the training loop and therefore metrics at different epochs get written to different plots.

```
tf.summary.scalar("training_accuracy", accu)
tf.summary.scalar("Validation_accuracy", valid_accu)
tf.summary.scalar("Validation_loss", val_loss)
```

What you can do is to define the summary ops before the loop with placeholders. Then, in the eval loop, you can feed these tensor with real values.

```
# Define a placeholder and wire it to the summary op.
accu_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
tf.summary.scalar("training_accuracy", accu_tensor)
summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

# Create a session after defining ops.
sess = tf.Session()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(<some-directory>, sess.graph)

for i in range(total_iterations,
               total_iterations + num_iteration):
    # run training ops to get values for accu
    # ...

    # run the summary op with a feed_dict to feed the value.
    summaries = sess.run(summary_op, feed_dict={accu_tensor: accu})
    writer.add_summary(summaries, epoch)
```

Comment: Can you tell me where should the `writer=tf.summary.FileWriter(options.tensorboard,session)` go. As i am getting a new error after making the necessary modifications. `TypeError: The passed graph must be an instance of `Graph` or the deprecated `GraphDef`
`

Comment: It should be after you have created a session e.g. `session = tf.Session()` --generally it is after defining all tensors and ops.

Comment: I modified my answer a little bit to include the lines for `sess` and `writer`.